# Google search assistance functionality in jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

While typing for search on google it provide assistance for search.
eg: typing 'ti' provides timesofindia,tin,timesjobs.
Same purpose is needed while tying i need to fetch data for backend and need to provide assist.
Is there any jquery plugin or any javascript.?
Any way of help is appreciated. :)

Comment: it seems u did not try anything?there are n number autocomplete or autosuggestion based javascript frameworks http://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=2&gs_id=y&xhr=t&q=autocomplete+javascript&pq=autosuggestion+javascript&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=au+javascript&aq=0c&aqi=g-c4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=bb4200f2eeeb84b9&ion=1&biw=1024&bih=653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the JQuery autocomplete plugin in JQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

You should use AJAX to load the data while user typing though, and put the loaded data into the jquery autocomplete plugin.